# Redis connection error

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm trying to start a npm server with Redis. I'm in a team and it works for everybody except me. We use vagrant. When I start my server with `npm start`, I have the following error:

```
Warning: connect-redis reported a client error: Error: Redis connection to /var/run/redis/redis.sock failed - connect ENOENT /var/run/redis/redis.sock
```

I checked, I have the right to write and read inside the folder `/var/run/` but the file `redis.sock` doesn't exist.

Do you know why I'm seeing this error?

Comment: Try to make sure your redis instance is up and running by executing `redis-cli ping`

Comment: Something was wrong in my redis.conf Also I make sure if my redis instance is up and it was. Thanks for your help